# Расположить элементы строк, находящихся в главной диагонали, в порядке возрастания

Tags: массивы, матрицы, pascal, строки

Дан массив размерности nxn. Элементы строк, находящиеся выше главной диагонали (не включая главную диагональ), расположить в порядке возрастания, а затем переписать их в виде вектора (по строкам) в одномерный массив Y, начиная с левого верхнего угла. (Определить размерность массива Y в зависимости от размерности массива X.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну что ж, разобьем задачу на несколько этапов.

### 1 Этап

**Опишем закон, по которому будем искать индексы нужных нам элементов.**

Главная диагональ это у нас вот эта:

```
|x| | | | |
| |x| | | |
| | |x| | |
| | | |x| |
| | | | |x|
```

Нам нужны все элементы, выше нее:

```
|x|O|O|O|O|
| |x|O|O|O|
| | |x|O|O|
| | | |x|O|
| | | | |x|
```

Их индексы описываются таким законом: **[i,j], где j > i, а j принадлежит промежутку [0; n) (i и j строка и столбец соответственно, кол-во строк/столбцов)**.

Пол решения у нас есть, мы знаем и можем находить нужные нам элементы по их индексу.

### 2 Этап

**Отсортируем нужные нам элементы построчно с этими элементами**

Воспользуемся классическим академическим методом сортировки, а именно методом пузырька. Суть метода в том, что мы сравниваем текущий элемент массива с последующими и меняем их местами, если текущий элемент больше последующего. Т.е. чем больше элемент, тем дальше он будет находится от начала массива. Алгоритм проще некуда, гуглится легко.

### 3 Этап

**Определим размер выходного массива**
Он равен сумме всем возможным комбинаций индексов закона описанного в 1 этапе.
Т.е. sum(n - i) где n - константа равная кол-ву столбцов, i - переменная, изменяющаяся [1, n). Т.е. для 5 столбцов получится такой вот результат:
(5-1) + (5 - 2) + (5 - 3) + (5 - 4) = 10

Т.е. алгоритм ясен и очень даже прост.

Осталось заполнить все эти элементы значениями из матрицы. Для этого достаточно по закону из первого этапа пробежаться по всем элементам и складывать их последовательно в результирующий массив.

Задача для 9 класса средней школы решена, вуаля!

---

Описания программного кода, методов и др. оставляю вам, к тому же все уже здесь есть.

## [Более расширенный пример](https://87691d3178d90ca50d65e8885c36dc11de749739.googledrive.com/host/0B8vPxB65sZYMUUpkODNKM3JMMVk)

Comment: Что здесь подразумевается под вектором?

Пока что удалось решить только 2 этап задачи:

http://ontext.info/62562

Comment: Это одномерный массив.

Comment: Да, кстати, вы бы лучше код форматировали (отступы и все такое). Улучшает читаемость да и люди другие смогут нормально читать.
Так же общепринят сервис для выкладывания исходников с подсветкой http://pastebin.com/

Comment: Добавил изменения в ответ

Comment: Кодил на Python, т.к. на Pascal я уже почти не помню, да и лезть в совсем мертвый язык не хочется что-то...

Comment: Благодарю за хороший разбор задания. Осталось только на паскале это накатать.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8eGn0JCR